# Help understanding theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

So this is my first semester taking a Real Analysis class. We are using the book Introduction to Analysis by Gaughan 5th ed. This is my first real Math class and I'm really excited but I am having trouble following some of the most basic proofs. 
[image: thm 0.21]
[image: thm 0.22]

So in theorem 0.21. Can you explain the part Hence there is $m\in A$ s.t. $n_0-1<m\leq n_0$. Where is this coming from? Is this coming from the definition of being bound from above?

In theorem 0.22 how are they getting $0<\frac{1}{y-x}<N$ also $Nx$ where it states that $n\leq Nx < n+1$.

Also in other proofs where they set $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$ or something similar.

Thanks. Also tips.

Answer (score 2):

$n_0$ is an upper bound, meaning that every element of $A$ is less than it. $n_0-1$ is not an upper bound, meaning some element of $A$ is greater than it. Thus this number falls between the two.

$0<\frac{1}{y-x}<N$ holds by using 0.21 to find an $n$ such that $n\leq\frac{1}{y-x}<n+1$ and setting $N=n+1$.

$n\leq Nx<n+1$ is exactly what 0.21 asserts happens, I'm not sure how this can be confusing.

Comment: Alright thanks I get the first theorem now. Sorry I'm still a bit confused on 2, where does $\frac{1}{y-x}$ come from, Archimedean principle?

Comment: In the proof of first theorem I would suggest adding "And $ m\leq x$ because $m\in A. $" just before the last sentence of  the first paragraph, so  it is clear where $m\leq x$ came from in $m\leq x<m+1.$

Comment: @HiPolyEraser $\frac{1}{y-x}$ is a number that the author picks because it makes clever things happen. It's a real number whose existence is justified by the fact that $x\neq y$, it's not the result of a theorem.

Comment: We start with $x$ and $y$ with $x<y$ So the number $1/(y-x)$ exists and is positive by the basic rules of arithmetic.

Comment: alright thanks.